# Create file at Remote directory in sftp

Tags: unix, ftp, sftp

I want to place one file at Remote directory
Server : dsfjnejfn.co.in 
User:gytkl
I am trying below commands

`sftp gytkl@dsfjnejfn.co.in`

`sftp> put dummy.txt`
I am getting below error message
`sftp> put dummy.txt
stat dummy.txt: No such file or directory`

Can anyone please tell me how to place the file at FTP directory ?

Comment: Do you have a file named `dummy.txt` in the directory from which you started `sftp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try entering the entire path for the file dummy.txt. The seems to not be able to find the source file in the current directory.

Best.